# Half press on Nikon D90 triggers shooting

Tags: nikon, autofocus, nikon-d90, shooting-mode

I'm starting to learn photography and, in one of the videos I watched, the guy said that its good to first half press the shooting button (on auto focus settings and P mode) and then full press to get the photo. But, in my D90, when I half press the button, it automatically shoots when it finds focus. How can I disable it, so I can find focus with half press, correct the photo and then full press to take the photo?

All settings are default, except Autofocus -> a1 -> Single point

Comment: Is there no point on a slow press that the camera focusses but does not take a picture?

Comment: @BobT No. it automatically shoots in a half press. By the way, full press seems to not work, because after shoot is done while half press, it doesn't shoot when I resume to full press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shutter button could be defective. If it is, then consider using back button focusing (repurposes the AE-L button as focus). It's a lot cheaper than getting your camera fixed. There are many tutorials on line. I like this [tutorial](https://shuttermuse.com/how-to-set-up-double-back-button-autofocus-on-nikon-cameras-for-quick-af-point-switching/) since it explains a number of options. It takes some time to become accustomed to this technique. I set mine up for AF-C since it allows me to follow action if necessary.